# audit log in azure using powershell for remoteapp

Tags: powershell, azure, remoteapp

I am trying to get logs in azure using following commands

Get-AzureRmLog
This command gets logs for past one hour
I have done some operation of remote app collections.

Above command has filter of ResourceProvider to get logs
Have tried giving
Get-AzureRmLog ResourceProvider = "RemoteApp Service"
But unable to get logs

Can i get some information of getting logs for collection in remoteapp
such as crate/delete collection , assign/dassign user to collections.

Also what ResourceProvider should i provide for remoteapp logs

Answer (score 1):

The AzureRM cmdlets are actually using the new Resource Manager (RM) APIs - including the new portal. Unfortunately, RemoteApp is not yet available in the new portal (and therefore via Resource Manager), but that is scheduled for the near future: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/remoteapp-roadmap/

You can still see the RemoteApp operations via the old portal -> Management Services.